# Using require in vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

I try to use import(xxx) in vite to replace require(xxx), but import(xxx) will return a promise(async), how can I write like require(xxx) in vite?

```js
let lang = require(`./${path}.json`)
```

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T96sN.png)

I try to change it to import(`./${path}.json`) but it will return a Promise, so that I can't get the index with file.

Comment: Inside the package.json file add a line  `"type": "commonjs"` and see tell me if its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top-level await has decent support in [browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=top-level+await) and is available in Node as of two years ago, so you can do:

```
const lang = await import(`./${path}.json`, { assert: { type: "json" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved, just install package `vite-require` than require is work on vite.